# SBT package only a set of classes

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a play (java) multi module project and I want to package one module twice but with different set of classes.

so my tree looks like this

```
projectA
   |
   |- modele_1
   |        |-- build.sbt
   |        |-- app
   |             |
   |             |- com.package.one --> package this as one.jar
   |             |- com.package.two
   |        
   |
   |- modeule_2
   |
   |- build.sbt
```

I want to create two jars from the `module_1`. One of the jar will be called `one.jar` and will only contain files from the package `com.package.one` and the other will contain everything including the package of `one.jar`.

I tried to create a custom compile plugin in `module_1/build.sbt` but it doesn't seem to work

```
lazy val PluginApi = config("pluginApi").extend(Compile)

inConfig(PluginApi)(Defaults.compileSettings)

mappings in (PluginApi, packageBin) := {
  val original = (mappings in (PluginApi, packageBin)).value
  original.filter { case (file, toPath) => toPath.startsWith("com/package/one/") }
}

unmanagedSourceDirectories in PluginApi := (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile).value
```

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: @YuchenZhong unfortunately no :( moved out the 'submodule' to a separate project